# <input type="number"> not displaying correctly on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Well, at first, it displays correctly, but then when you scroll down the page, the tiny spinners also move, which is quite bizarre! The version I'm using is Chrome 16.0.912.75. Is it just me, or is this a widely known phenomenon? Here's a screen shot of what I'm talking about. :)

Do you guys know of a fix for this? If not, I might just opt for a simple textbox and perform validation via javascript.. :(

[image]

Comment: could you give us more code? I'm unable to reproduce this.